# Speed up image loading in a gtk.IconView

Tags: python, image, gtk, pygtk, pixbuf

I want to display a 139 cols * 121 rows image map.

(The image size is 32*32 px)

I use a `gtk.Iconview` with a `gtk.ListStore` that I fill with `gtk.gdk.Pixbuf`, like this :

(the two dimensional `graph` list contains objects that contain the images path to display)

```
pixbuf_passage = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_xpm_data(xpmdata)
for row in graph :
    for col in row :
        pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(col.img_base)

        if col.passage :
            pixbuf_passage.composite(pixbuf, 0, 0, pixbuf_passage.props.width, pixbuf_passage.props.height, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0, gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR, 255)

        self.grid.listStore.append([pixbuf, tooltip])
```

My problem is that the image loading time can be quite long, depending on the computer's configuration :

- ~20s for a Intel Core i7 with 4Gb RAM (which is acceptable)
- ~160s for a AMD X2 4200+ with 4Gb RAM (which is too long)

Is there any way to speed up the image loading ?
Perhaps the use of a gtk.Iconview isn't optimal here ?

Thanks

Comment: There's a [related discussion](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq13.043.htp) in the PyGTK FAQ which you can try. If that doesn't help, you can probably implement some sort of on-demand loading (IIRC Rhythmbox (or was it Banshee?) does this), but I imagine it's not easy.

Comment: Which version of GTK are you using ? On which platform ?

Comment: @liberforce : I use the 2.24.0 version of PyGTK and the 2.24.8 version of GTK, on Linux (x64) but there is the same effect on windows.

Comment: @Johannes Sasongko : I always forget to go see the PyGTK FAQ which is a 'gold mine' though. I've just tested to freeze IconView updates and detach the model before adding the pixbuf. The loading takes now 5s, instead of 20s ! (I can't test now on the other machine but I guess I could hardly do better). Thanks ! Can you post your solution as an answer instead of comment so I'll can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PyGTK FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq13.043.htp) has a few tips for this. The most important seems to be that you should freeze the treeview/iconview and unset its model temporarily while adding a lot of entries.

```
treeview.freeze_child_notify()
treeview.set_model(None)

# Add rows to the model
# ...

treeview.set_model(model)
treeview.thaw_child_notify()
```

The trick using g_idle_add is also useful to add more responsiveness to the UI.